# How can I reconcile dates between two tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking to solve an issue of potential dates missing from a Snowflake table. What I tried to do is create a table with calendar dates between 2017-2022 (minus weekends) based on a specific ID that I know has all expected dates. I have another table that has IDs where dates are missing and I would like to cross-reference with the first table to see the NULLs.

For example,

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 2017-01-01 |
| ID | 2017-01-02 |
| ID | 2017-01-03 |

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ID | NULL |
| ID | 2017-01-02 |
| ID | NULL |

I'm trying to join these two tables to see where the NULLs exist in the second table (rows 1 and 3), however the results I'm getting back are the dates that do exist rather than the NULLs. I tried different joins but it doesn't seem to help.

My sample query:

```
select distinct id, c.date, a.date
from (select distinct date
from first table
where date between '2017-01-01' and '2022-12-31'
and id = 'ID') as a
left join "second table" c
on c.date = a.date 
where c.id = 'id'
and c.date between '2017-01-01' and '2022-12-31'
order by c.date
```

Comment: Your left join is behaving like an inner join because `where c.id = 'id'
and c.date between '2017-01-01' and '2022-12-31'` ensures no nulls are returned from the second table. Make that condition part of your `left join` instead of `where` clause

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you for your assistance. Can you explain a little more on why I had to move the condition to the left join? Or if you know of literature that would explain this, that would be great.

Comment: In your case, your where clause basically gets rid of the rows from your second table where left joins would have produced a null

Comment: ^That happens because the where clause gets executed on the output of an outer join